# Python prevent copying object as reference

Tags: python

Is it possible to copy an object in Python without copying a reference?

For example, if I define a class

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0
```

and then create an instance

```
someObject = SomeClass()
someObject.value = 12
```

and I try to copy it to another instance:

```
anotherObject = someObject
```

and try to modify a property,

```
anotherObject.value = 10
```

the original property gets modified:

```
print someObject.value #prints 10
```

Is there any way to prevent this from happening? To clarify, I want the `anotherObject.value` to contain `10`, but I want `someObject.value` to still contain the original `12`. Is this possible in python?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The problem is, with

```
anotherObject = someObject
```

you don't copy the object, but just add another reference to it. To copy an object, try this:

```
from copy import copy

anotherObject = copy(someObject)
```

Comment: Can I make an object non-copyable? Similar to deleting operator= in c++?

Answer (score 29):

```
import copy

obj2 = copy.deepcopy(obj2)
```

Comment: Use `deepcopy` when you are working with nested objects. `copy` won´t do the trick there!

Answer (score 10):

As you've noticed, `anotherObject = someObject` doesn't make a copy - if you want a copy, try

```
import copy
otherObject = copy.copy(someObject)
```

The `copy.copy` vs `copy.deepcopy` distinction is important here - you can get away with `copy.copy` for the simple object you've described, but a more nested object would require `copy.deepcopy`.

`copy.copy(someObject)` makes a copy only of the object `someObject`, but if `someObject` contains references to other objects that can be changed ("mutable" objects) as in

```
someObject.value.this_one_has_values_too = 4
```

or

```
someObject.value[0] = 1
```

or

```
someObject.value['key'] = 'value'
```

then *references* to those objects will be made in the copy. If you use `copy.deepcopy`, they'll also be copied over.

A great way to gain an understanding of this is playing with the [Online Python Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=x+%3D+%5B1,+2,+3%5D%0Ay+%3D+%5B4,+5,+6%5D%0Az+%3D+y%0Ay+%3D+x%0Ax+%3D+z%0A%0Ax+%3D+%5B1,+2,+3%5D+%23+a+different+%5B1,+2,+3%5D+list!%0Ay+%3D+x%0Ax.append%284%29%0Ay.append%285%29%0Az+%3D+%5B1,+2,+3,+4,+5%5D+%23+a+different+list!%0Ax.append%286%29%0Ay.append%287%29%0Ay+%3D+%22hello%22%0A%0A%0Adef+foo%28lst%29%3A%0A++++lst.append%28%22hello%22%29%0A++++bar%28lst%29%0A%0Adef+bar%28myLst%29%3A%0A++++print%28myLst%29%0A%0Afoo%28x%29%0Afoo%28z%29&mode=display&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=2&curInstr=0) (see linked example) but here's a straightforward demonstration of the behavior without the useful diagraming Online Python Tutor provides.

```
>>> import copy
>>> class Foo(object):
...     pass
...
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.value = 1
>>> f.nested_value = [2,3,4]
>>> deep = copy.deepcopy(f)
>>> deep.value = 5
>>> f.value
1
>>> deep.nested_value.append(6)
>>> f.nested_value
[2, 3, 4]
>>> shallow = copy.copy(f)
>>> shallow.value = 7
>>> f.value
1
>>> shallow.nested_value.append(8)
>>> f.nested_value
[2, 3, 4, 8]
```

Edit: But what about the integer in the first example? It's actually being shared between the `f` object and the `shallow` object, but that's not a problem - it's not editable; we can't change an integer object like `1` to be any different, so we might as well save memory and use that one object anytime any Python object needs a reference to 1.

**The** thing to read about this is Ned's [Facts and Myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: What is the difference between a `copy` and a `deepcopy`? Also, what do you mean by `nested object`? I'm new to python and I just want to learn as much as possible.

Comment: @coder108 does this make sense? If not, please let me know what doesn't so I can improve the answer.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean by `nested objects`. Just out of curiosity, isn't an integer also an object? Why isn't `deepcopy` necessary for that? Thank you for the link, btw. It is very useful.

Comment: @coder108 *terrific* question - both objects actually _use the same integer_. Why isn't this a problem? Because it's an immutable object; there's no way to take an integer object 1 and change it.

Comment: The small but nice difference between `copy` and `deepcopy` really helped me with nested objects!

Answer (score 6):

```
import copy
```

In some cases just:

```
copy_obj = copy.copy(obj)
```

is enough but in other cases you should use:

```
copy_obj = copy.deepcopy(obj)
```

Comment: What are those cases?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`copy`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) for that. Try the following:

```
someObject = SomeClass()
someObject.value = 12
anotherObject = copy.copy(someObject)
anotherObject.value = 10
```

Now `someObject.value` will still be 12. You will have to place `import copy` at the top of your script though.